# How to flip a path drawn on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to flip drawing drawn on a `canvas`. Please refer to the code at http://jsfiddle.net/hhzhR/1/. Please notice that the code there draws a 'L'. If I uncomment the code `ctx.scale(1, -1);` then nothing is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you flip the canvas, the path gets drawn out of the canvas region. You have to translate the canvas too:

```
ctx.translate(0, canvas.height);
```

like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hhzhR/2/).